# Jboss7.2 Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra

Tags: server, jboss, cdi, jboss7.x

Environment:

- Jboss 7.2
- Java 11

On loading JBoss 7.2 server I am getting an issue obtaining CDI 1.1 utilities.  How could I to resolve this problem?

**Server log SEVERE error on loading**

```
...
08:24:15,561 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.flow] (MSC service thread 1-7) Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra
08:24:15,562 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application.view] (MSC service thread 1-7) Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra
...
```

Comment: In spite of this servere error log, red hat gives no imporance an it is solved from 7.3+ version as we can see in the following link https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3906401